# BigQuery ODBC Driver error - failed to decrypt data

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc

On a number of our windows machines we are getting the following error when attempting to use the Bigquery ODBC driver to bring BigQuery Data into Excel.

[DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [HY000][Simba][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data: Key not valid for use in specified state.

This error appeared suddenly on machines where the driver was working - perhaps due to a windows update?

We have tried installing/uninstalling the latest driver - switching to/from 32-bit version of the driver and Excel. Nothing has worked so far.

In the latest release notes for the driver under known issues:

[latest odbc release notes](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/release-notes-2.5.0.1001.txt)

```
* [GAUSS-1535] On Windows, encrypted connection property values cannot be 
   decrypted. This is due to a security update. The following properties are 
   affected and must be regenerated:
   - Auth_AccessToken
   - Auth_BaseRedirectUri
   - Auth_Client_ID
   - Auth_Client_Secret
   - Auth_CompletedRedirectUri
   - Auth_RefreshToken
   - AuthorizationUrl
   - ByoidSubjectToken
   - ClientId
   - ClientSecret
   - KeyFile
   - KeyFilePath
   - ProxyPwd
   - RefreshToken
```

This seems to be the problem I am experiencing - but it is quite vague and I am
unclear as to how I am to regenerate these properties. An uninstall/re-install of the ODBC drivers did not seem to help and googling these terms did not provide any other answers - other than they seem to be ODBC related.

Thanks for any assistance.

Update: I found that the previous version of the driver - 2.4.6.1015 fixes the problem.

Comment: Lets look at your connection string to BigQuery.  Are there parameters in the connection string that are themselves encrypted?  If yes, that would seem to match the report.  I am imagining a connection string that may have a password "PASSWORD" but the password value is encrypted "&tyTv#34Jk" ... and the message says that the ODBC driver can no longer decrypt the encrypted connection properties.

See also:  https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/ERROR-Simba-Driver-Support-1030-Failed-to-decrypt-data-Key-not/td-p/2394556

Comment: Hit the same problem. The logs for the DSN showed that ClientId was showing as “***” and it could not be decrypted, this aligns with the release notes. 

We’re you able to resolve this?

Comment: I found a work around. The previous version of the driver - 2.4.6.1015 does not have this issue. For the time being we have downgraded to this version and so far it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

The previous version of the driver seems to resolve this issue - 2.4.6.1015